# Referencing using extra information

Tags: bibliographies

I want to create a command that referencences a bibliographical cite, but some extra information using hyperlink. I want that clicking on "A reference to *This Book [1]* including This Book send me to the [1] in the bibliography. But it sends me to the end of the document

```
\newcommand{\citar}[1]{%
\hyperlink{cite.#1}{\textit{\citefield{#1}{title}}\textsuperscript{\cite{#1}}}%
```

}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, edit your question to include the fragment in a compilable document (even with error) that shows exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Doesn't `hyperref` do this by default?

Comment: Usually, you have to turn this off for references if you don't want it. Did you try just loading `hyperref` and citing things? If it doesn't just work, we need a compilable example demonstrating the problem.